# Can I add an audio from my computer to a video I already uploaded in Youtube?

Tags: youtube

I uploaded a video a while ago to my Youtube channel and now I want to add a mp3 file I made to it. When I go to edit video, I can only see the option to add audio from the Youtube library to the video, but not from my computer. Is this possible?

Can I add an audio from my computer to a video I already uploaded in Youtube?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### No, you cannot

The `Add` options in the [YouTube Studio](https://studio.youtube.com/) audio editor only allow you to select music and sound effects from YouTube's own [Audio Library](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3376882).

If you want to add something from outside the [Audio Library](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3376882), you will need to do it locally on your PC and re-upload the video.

##### Resources

- [Add an audio track to your YouTube video](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/94316)
- [YouTube Audio Library](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/3376882)
- [YouTube Studio](https://studio.youtube.com/)